# Formatting FOR Cycle Output every 3 results

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have this code:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); $db->setQuery("SELECT data, numero, totale
FROM generico_fatturazione_fatture_clienti WHERE documento = '4' 
AND data BETWEEN (SELECT dalla_data_ FROM statistiche_andamento_aziendale WHERE id = 1) 
AND (SELECT alla_data_ FROM statistiche_andamento_aziendale WHERE id = 1)");
$risultato = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($risultato == null) {echo '<b>0</b>';}
elseif ($risultato == 0) {echo '<b>0</b>';}
else { echo '<br>';
foreach($risultato as $value) {foreach($value as $key => $data){ echo $data;} }
} ?>
```

For every query i got: "Value 1, Value 2, Value 3" so I got the values for: "data, numero, totale".
Is there a way to get a list for each 3 results formatted like:

```
FIRST RESULT:
 - Data: Value 1
 - Numero: Value 2
 - Totale: Value 3
SECOND RESULT:
 - Data: Value 1
 - Numero: Value 2
 - Totale: Value 3
```

etc etc?

I've fixed the code and now output looks more acceptable, i just need to converte the first value (data string) to another format:

```
<?php $db = JFactory::getDBO(); $db->setQuery("
SELECT data, numero, totale
FROM generico_fatturazione_fatture_clienti WHERE documento = '4' 
AND data BETWEEN (SELECT dalla_data_ FROM statistiche_andamento_aziendale WHERE id = 1) 
AND (SELECT alla_data_ FROM statistiche_andamento_aziendale WHERE id = 1)");
$risultato = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($risultato == null) {echo '<b>0</b>';}
elseif ($risultato == 0) {echo '<b>0</b>';}
else { echo '<br>';
foreach($risultato as $value) {
$i= 0;
foreach($value as $key => $data){ 
$i++;

if($i == 1) { $class = 'Data: '; }
elseif($i == 2) { $class = 'Fattura Numero: '; }
elseif($i == 3) { $class = 'Totale (€): '; }
if ($i == 3) {$newline = '<br>';} else {$newline = null;}
$virgola = ',';

echo $class.' <b> '.$data.$virgola.' </b>'.$newline;
} }} ?>
```

Comment: Sure there is.  Have you made an attempt at generating output in that desired format?

Comment: I don't know how to separate the output every 3 value.

Comment: It seems as if you are talking about just separating each record, as each record has those three field.  You just need to output whatever layout you want for each row, within it iteration of your result set.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
foreach($risultato as $value) {
    echo '- Data: ' . $value->data . PHP_EOL;
    echo '- Numero: ' . $value->numero . PHP_EOL;
    echo '- Totale: ' . $value->totale . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-------------' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will this work? If not provide output of `print_r($risultato)`

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [data] => 2016-06-17 12:04:51 [numero] => 1 [totale] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [data] => 2016-06-17 16:24:43 [numero] => 2 [totale] => 146.4 ) )

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct but the date format wont display correctly for that you need minor change in your code

```
if($i == 1) { $class = 'Data: '; }
```

Add the date format here

```
if($i == 1) { $class = 'Data: '; 
     $date = new DateTime($data);
     $data = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
}
```